# Cakephp, Angular Rest preflight returns 404 on mapped resources

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, http, cakephp

Making a GET request from angular to a rest cake 2.x app.
The url being requested is using mapResources and is `/controllername/1.json` which should map to `view($id)`. 
When making this request with angular, the preflight is using method 'OPTIONS' and is returning a 404.

If I change the url to /controllername/view/1.json - The request works perfectly as expected. Can anyone shed some light on why the preflight returns 404?

Yes, I am making CORS requests. I also tried the request in Postman and it worked perfectly there as well.

**Update**
As a quick fix for now I added the following to the `beforeFilter()` in AppController

```
        if($this->request->is('options')){
            echo json_encode(array(true));
            die;
        }
```

What would be the downfalls of making this the permanent fix?

Comment: I am also using the same fix. But I think this fix return 'true' for all calls with the HTTP OPTIONS. Whether the requested URL is exists or not. In that way, the basic principle of pre-flight call is lost.